# Average degree of a graph and minimum degree of a subgraph

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose we have a graph $G$ with at least 1 edge.

I know that $G$ has a subgraph $H$ where $\delta(H)$, the minimum degree of $H$, satisfies $\delta(H) \geq d(G)/2$, where $d(G)$ is the average degree of $G$.

I wish to show that for any $k<2$, $G$ does not necessarily have a subgraph $H'$ such that $\delta(H') \geq d(G)/k$.

I assumed this was equivalent to showing that $G$ does not necessarily have a subgraph $H$ that satisfies $\delta(H) > d(G)/2$. That is, there exists $G$ where every subgraph $H$ satisfies $\delta(H) \leq d(G)/2$.

However, I have not been able to find one. Is there a graph $G$ with at least 1 edge that satisfies such a condition? Or is there a flaw in my reasoning?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: For the second part: The two conditions are not necessarily equivalent because $\delta(H)$ can be strictly larger than $d(G)/2$ and yet strictly smaller than $d(G)/k$ (for $k<2$). Rather prove: for every fixed $k$, there exists a graph $G$ (which may depend on $k$).